# What is the docker run -e equivalent in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I can't get environmental variables in a docker-compose file written directly in it to work. A similar configuration with the command line work just fine like this:

```
docker run --name container_name -d --network=my-net --mount type=bind,src=/Users/t2wu/Documents/Work/Dodo/Intron-Exon_expression/DockerCompose/intronexon_db/mnt_mysql,dst=/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_DATABASE=db_name -e MYSQL_USER=username -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=passwd mysql/mysql-server:8.0.13
```

This is an MySQL instance which sets three environmental variables: MYSQL_DATABASE, MYSQL_USER and MYSQL_PASSWORD. I'm later able to launch bash into it `docker exec -it container_name bash` and launch the client `mysql  -u username -p` and connects just fine.

However when I write it in a `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  intronexon_db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:8.0.13
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./intronexon_db/mnt_mysql
        target: /var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_name
      MYSQL_USER: username
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: passwd
    networks:
      - my-net

networks:
  my-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Then when I use the mysql client, it's as if the user doesn't exist. How do I set it so that it is equivalent to the `-e` flag during docker run?

**EDIT**

`docker-compose --version` shows `docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b`

**EDIT 2**
The environmental flag did work. But I run into problem because:

1. Part of the problem was that it takes MySQL sometime to get the database, username and password setup ready. And I was checking it way too early.
2. I need to specify localhost for some reason: `mysql --host=localhost -u user -p`. Specifying `127.0.0.1` will not work.
3. For some unknown reason the example stack.yml from the official docker image did not have to specify `--host` when the `adminer` container is run. If I wipe out the adminer, then `--host` flag needs to be given.
4. Sometimes MySQL daemon will stop. It might has to do with my mount target `/var/lib/mysql` but I'm not certain.
5. `command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` is actually significant. I don't know why when I did `docker run` I didn't need to do anything about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docker-compose accept both types of ENVs either an array or a dictionary, better to double or try both approaches.

**environment**

> Add environment variables. You can use either an array or a
>   dictionary. Any boolean values; true, false, yes no, need to be
>   enclosed in quotes to ensure they are not converted to True or False
>   by the YML parser.
>
> Environment variables with only a key are resolved to their values on
>   the machine Compose is running on, which can be helpful for secret or
>   host-specific values.

```
environment:
  RACK_ENV: development
  SHOW: 'true'
  SESSION_SECRET:
```

or

```
environment:
  - RACK_ENV=development
  - SHOW=true
  - SESSION_SECRET
```

Might be something with [docker-compose version](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) as it working fine with `3.1`. as the offical image suggested, so Better to try [offical image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

Also, better to debug such cases where everything seems correct but some minor syntax is missing. you can test it before working with DB.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  intronexon_db:
    image: alpine
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: myDb
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

run `docker-compose up`

Now test and debug in testing enviroment.

```
docker exec -it composeenv_intronexon_db_1 ash -c "printenv"
```

Comment: 1. My docker-compose version is 1.24.1, build 4667896b. 2. The dashed version doesn't work for me. `services.intronexon_db.environment contains {"MYSQL_DATABASE": "intronexon_db"}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string`

Comment: try this and this shoudl work ```db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example```

Comment: OK dashed configuration aside, I see that `docker exec -it dockercompose_intronexon_db_1 bash -c "printenv"` shows the environment is in there. So that's not where the problem is.

Comment: BTW I did and am using the official image. Your last reply I could not understand?

Comment: I mean the suggested offical `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: Oh I missed that! The example works, at least I can login to MySQL with the mysql client as root. Now I have to figure out why mine doesn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the environment params in your yml need the - in front of them could be the likely culprit

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  intronexon_db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:8.0.13
    volumes:
      - ./intronexon_db/mnt_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE: db_name
      - MYSQL_USER: username
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD: passwd
    networks:
      - my-net

networks:
  my-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: When I actually do that, it fails on me `services.intronexon_db.environment contains {"MYSQL_DATABASE": "intronexon_db"}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string`. I have docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b. But now I realized that the envs are there after docker runs. So my issue must be some other problem.